# How can I save the information of the custom attributes in woocommerce

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, hook-woocommerce

I need to be able to save the values of a custom tab called **Wine Properties** that my custom product has.

I have tried using the hook **woocommerce_process_product_meta**, with no luck. I leave the code I use below

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_process_product_meta', 'save_wine_options_field' );
function save_wine_options_field( $post_id, $post ) {

    //! Mas Vendidos
    $wine_best_seller = isset( $_POST['_wine_best_seller'] ) ? 'yes' : 'no';
    update_post_meta( $post_id, '_wine_best_seller', $wine_best_seller );
    //! Top Love
    $wine_top_love = isset( $_POST['_wine_top_love'] ) ? 'yes' : 'no';
    update_post_meta( $post_id, '_wine_top_love', $wine_top_love );
    //! Añada del vino pa_idgl_best_sellers 
    $wine_vintage_select = $_POST['_wine_vintage_select'];
    if( !empty( $wine_vintage_select ) ){
        update_post_meta( $post_id, '_wine_vintage_select', esc_attr( $wine_vintage_select ) );
    } else {
        update_post_meta( $post_id, '_wine_vintage_select',  '' );
    }
    //! Texto añada del vino
    $wine_vintage_text = $_POST['_wine_vintage_text'];
    if ( isset( $wine_vintage_text ) ) {
        update_post_meta( $post_id, '_wine_vintage_text', sanitize_text_field( $wine_vintage_text ) );
    }
}
```

Thank you

Comment: What code did you use to create the custom tab? can you add it? because it affects the code to save. Regards

Comment: It's solved! it was a problem with my custom tab! Thank You